# Wrong screenshot size

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-xr

I am trying to submit a new iOS app and I am struggling with the XR screenshot size.

Apple requires that the XR screenshoots size is **1242 x 2688** ([Apple guide](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925)) but screenshots from the actual device (not from the simulator) are: **750 x 1624**.

I have tried to take the screenshots in both ways:

1) on the phone via buttons

2) via Xcode 10

Unfortunately, I cannot take the screenshots from the simulator because my app uses the ARKit which hovewer provides screenshots with another different size: 828 × 1792.

**Side note**: the XS max simulator provides screenshot of the right size but I don't have a XS max device to test.

How do I get screenshots with the right size?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check under settings > Display & Brightness and then display zoom. You may have your device zoomed in which can alter the dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, I had the device zoomed. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem completely. Without zoom the screenshot size is: 828 × 1792. Not the expected 1242 x 2688.

Comment: Also having the same problem. Was this ever sorted?

Comment: Actually not. I managed to resize the screenshot to the required size using GIMP.